# Don't show country in results of Google AutoComplete

Tags: autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api, country

I'm struggling with this issue for a while now, didn't find any hint in google's documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

I want to show the suggested addresses returned from google api without the country name, is there a way to do it ?

Comment: have you defined the country in the places request? I don't have country showing in mine, it was a while that I coded a solution, but my api request reads `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo $google_key; ?>&libraries=geometry,places&language=en&region=uk" type="text/javascript"></script>` and my autocomplete reads `autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('zipcode')), { types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions:{country:"uk"}});`. Is this any use to you?

Comment: thanks. looks better, now in the suggestions I don't see the country, however after I pick one the country appears in the selected value. do you see it also in the selected value or not ?

Comment: this is actually the value of formatted_address field in the returned result, I have a method that format the actual string value that will be presented in the textbox so I can easily manipulate it, just wonder if there's a way to return the formatted_address without country already

Comment: Hi Tamir did you figure this out? sorry about coming back to you so late.

Comment: hi. yes, I did. your code solved the problem for suggested values, for the selected one I simply formatted the value of formatted_address that was assigned to text box as is. I'm not sure if there's a way to get the formatted_address already without country, but this solution is good enough for me :)